# Adding Bookmarks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-extensions

So, today I noticed an odd behavior with bookmarks in my Firefox. If I hit Ctrl-D, or Choose Add Bookmarks from the Bookmarks menu, it automatically adds without asking which folder to put it in. Has anyone ever seen this before and/or solved it? When I run it in safe mode it works, so it must be an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually looks like it was the BlackSheep extension. Once I disabled that it worked just fine.

Comment: You should accept the answer too, so it shows the question has a solution. Just click the empty tick.

Comment: @Joe he won't be able to accept for another 2 days

Answer (score 2):

If you press Ctrl + D the current page gets saved as a "Unclassified" bookmark (I don't know if that's the word in english) You can find this bookmarks if you click on the bookmarks menu and then "Organize" bookmarks (alternatively press Ctrl + Shift + O)

You can also press Ctrl + D again in order to choose where to save the bookmark.

And by the way, pressing Ctrl + D is the same as clicking on the star on the right side of the address bar.

Comment: It actually looks like it was the BlackSheep extension. Once I disabled that it worked just fine.